# showing and hiding a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have used the below code to position a `UIView` which will hold various buttons ect. I am showing  this view in an `IBAction` method for a button.

How would I have the user be able to click on the button to show the `UIView` in a default position, then, when the user clicks on the button again, move the `UIView` back off screen?

Am I doing the best thing moving the `UIView` on/off screen or would it be better to just hide/show the controller?

I like the idea of moving it as it kinda looks like its moving downward (not that its animated or anything). Actualy how would I animate this to move slower?

```
CGRect f = self.optionsuiview.frame;
f.origin.x = 0;
f.origin.y = 42;
self.optionsuiview.frame = f;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a property of the button (ctrl+drag to header file) you can use this to change the state of the button, so you can dictate when the view moves up/down.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *yourButton;
```

Within your IBAction method could look something like this

```
 -(IBAction)yourButtonPressed:(id)sender{

if (self.yourButton.selected){

   self.yourButton.selected = NO;

   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
   CGRect f = self.optionsuiview.frame;
   f.origin.x = 0;
   f.origin.y = 42;
   self.optionsuiview.frame = f;
 }];
}

if (!self.yourButton.selected){
   self.yourButton.selected = YES;

   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
   CGRect f = self.optionsuiview.frame;
   f.origin.x = 0;
   f.origin.y = 0;
   self.optionsuiview.frame = f;
  }];
}
```

I hope this way helps with what you're looking for ,

Cheers, Jim.

Comment: I have tried this however giving me error on first line if (self.buttonname.selected){

Comment: I have declared the name of the button in h file still getting error tho

Answer (score 1):

> Am i doing the best thing moving the uiview on/off screen or would it be better to just hide/show the controller?

Only you or your UX advisor can answer that...

You would hide the view again in the same way you show it, by changing the view frame. It's just that to hide it you're setting the frame to a location that is off screen. And the same logic applies for animation too:

// to show

```
// calculate `f` here to a location off screen to animate to

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                 animations:^{
        self.optionsuiview.frame = f;
    }
                 completion:^{
        self.optionsuiview.hidden = YES;
    }];
```

*(note that we hide the view after the animation so it isn't considered a tap target)*

Showing the view is the same in reverse. Set `hidden` to `NO` and then animate the frame to a visible location.

Comment: Thanks for this. However im trying to figure out the if statment used to tell if the user has clicked on the button or not and if so show or hide the uiview any ideas? \

Comment: Use the `self.optionsuiview.hidden` flag.

Comment: yea i tried that and iv tryed if (self.optionuiview.hidden = YES ) { however it crashes on this line

Comment: What are the exception details?

Comment: None it just crashes on thread 1 breakpoint 1.1 how can if ind out any more details than this? sorry im very new to objective c

Comment: if (self.optionsuiview.hidden = YES){
    
        
        
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                CGRect f = self.optionsuiview.frame;
                f.origin.x = 0;
                f.origin.y = 42;
                self.optionsuiview.frame = f;
            }];
        }

Comment: I have also set to hidden = yes on view did load to ensure its hidden at launch

Comment: Hit continue. You have an all exception breakpoint? You need a stack trace and exception message...

Comment: sorry where do i press continue ? im using version 5 btw